# Write a code to calculate scores from and add them to a data.frame

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a data.frame with 6 columns. The first is for subjects, the second for blocks in an experiment, and columns 3,4 and 5 are values I need to calculate a binary score (0 or 1), that I want to add in the sixth column (that's why now, it's full of 0s).

```
head(kfdblock3to9)
    subject time        gr       ugr      sdugr IL
40002.3   40002    3 0.4475618 0.3706000 0.02994533  0
40002.4   40002    4 0.4361786 0.3901111 0.01846110  0
40002.5   40002    5 0.4279880 0.4550000 0.02811839  0
40002.6   40002    6 0.4313647 0.4134444 0.04352974  0
40002.7   40002    7 0.4420889 0.4394286 0.02883143  0
40002.8   40002    8 0.4325227 0.3960000 0.06559222  0
```

I'm trying to do this with a for loop, but I'm a beginner in R and I'm having difficulties with this. The scoring formula I'm trying to implement is one where:
If the value in column 3 ($gr) is less that the difference between the value in column 4 ($ugr) and .35 times the value in column 5 ($sdugr), then the subject receives a 1, otherwise a 0.

What I've tried so far is:

```
for (i in kfdblock3to9$subject) {
     if (kfdblock3to9$gr<(kfdblock3to9$ugr-(.35*kfdblock3to9$sdugr))) 
                 kfdblock3to9$IL=1
         else kfdblock3to9$IL=0
    }
```

This gives me 50 warnings, all saying:
"the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

I suppose I'm doing something wrong with the indexes then, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `within` and `ifelse` :

```
kfdblock3to9 <- 
within(kfdblock3to9,
  IL <- ifelse( gr < ugr - 0.35 * dugr, 1, 0)
)
```

`within()` isn't really that necessary, but it keeps your code a whole lot more readible and easier to understand.

Why does it go wrong? That's because your condition is vectorized : try

```
kfdblock3to9$gr<(kfdblock3to9$ugr-(.35*kfdblock3to9$sdugr))
```

and you will see it returns a logical vector. Now an `if()` clause can only deal with one boolean value at a time. If you have a vectorized result, you need a vectorized solution and that is `ifelse()`

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem I would suggest something like this:

```
kfdblock3to9[, "IL"] <- ifelse(kfdblock3to9$gr < (kfdblock3to9$ugr-(0.35*kfdblock3to9$sdugr)), 1, 0);
```

(A vectorized approach is mostly faster than a loop.)

Your loop is wrong because you don't respect your index `i`. You have to use `i` to access the row in the loop:

```
for (i in seq(along=kfdblock3to9)) {
    cat("row:", i, kfdblock3to9[i, "subject"], "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a logical test. You can thus avoid the use of the `loop`, and even `ifelse`, and simply do:

```
kfdblock3to9$IL <- with(kfdblock3to9, gr < (ugr-0.35*sdugr))
```

The IL column will include TRUE of FALSE, instead of 1 or 0. If you prefer having integers, you can do:

```
kfdblock3to9$IL <- as.integer(with(kfdblock3to9, gr < (ugr-0.35*sdugr)))
```

Comment: Please note that IL will be a logical vector in this case, which is different from the result of the code of OP.

Comment: Thanks! great use of the with function, which I didn't know about

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a loop in this case. Whenever you use a loop in the future, you need to use indices :

```
for (i in 1:length(kfdblock3to9$subject)) {
     if (kfdblock3to9[i,"gr"] < (kfdblock3to9[i, "ugr"] - .35 * kfdblock3to9[i, "sdugr"])) 
                 kfdblock3to9[i,"IL"]=1
     else  kfdblock3to9[i,"IL"]=0
}


kfdblock3to9
     subject time        gr       ugr      sdugr IL
40002.3   40002    3 0.4475618 0.3706000 0.02994533  0
40002.4   40002    4 0.4361786 0.3901111 0.01846110  0
40002.5   40002    5 0.4279880 0.4550000 0.02811839  1
40002.6   40002    6 0.4313647 0.4134444 0.04352974  0
40002.7   40002    7 0.4420889 0.4394286 0.02883143  0
40002.8   40002    8 0.4325227 0.3960000 0.06559222  0
```

Comment: You don't use indices for this, that's ridiculous

Comment: I wrote if s/he wanted to use *a loop*

Comment: which s/he shouldn't. There's a perfectly vectorized solution for this, using a loop is a waste of resources and making your code a whole lot more error-prone. I edited your first sentence to reflect this (and so I could remove the downvote)

Comment: Yes, that's why I commented on your solution and said that it was better. While there are better solutions, I think it is also useful to point out the problem with the OP's original code. Without knowing what the problem is with the original code, the OP may make similar mistakes in the future. That is all.

Comment: Thanks for all your tips and "error notifications" on my behalf. Indeed your responses are also good to learn what I was doing wrong "loop-wise".